# Last line of input not scanning in Java Scanner Class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to work on some stuff using the Scanner for input, but for some reason, the scanner is failing me.

I have the following code running, nothing complex:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
    }
```

Just as a test bed to make sure everything is being input correctly. If I copy my test material, say

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

The output omits the last line. I am pretty sure that it is because nextLine will only return a string if there is a string after it, even if it is empty, but I need it to work this way for the way I will eventually input the data to work. Does anyone know how I can fix this? My only guesses were to either use something other that scanner or to somehow append an empty string to the end of the input, but I wasn't sure how to do the second one, and I didn't think a different scanner-like thing would work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the input and what output are you getting?

Comment: If I copy the 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 shown above, it outputs 5, 4, 3, 2

Comment: Can you post some more code? It's not very clear what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line **MIGHT** not have a "enter" char. So it does not treat it as the end of line. Try

```
> 5
> 4
> 3
> 2
> 1
>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this on Eclipse just then. I didn't replicate Daryl Teo's suggestion; just the same input as what you provided in a .txt. Going straight to standard input, as well as pointing the `Scanner` to an input file got me the result you wanted, that is

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Could you please post some more code, as was requested in the comments? The error you have doesn't appear to be related to your `Scanner` at the moment, as weird as that sounds.